# @Value is not injected

Tags: spring, properties, code-injection

I'm trying to inject value from properties file into a spring configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ImagesContext {
   @Autowired
   @Value("${some.property.com}")
   private String property;

   @Bean
   public MyClass getMyClass() {
      return new MyClass(property);
   }
}
```

But the property is not injected correctly. Instead, when I debug, I see that the `property` string contains `${some.property.com}` and not the string value itself.

Comment: Have you got your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configured correctly and ensuring that its in the correct applicationcontext?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@Value` annotation is processed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is typically registered if you have a `<component-scan>` or `<annotation-config>` configuration in XML (or directly with a bean definition). You need to add either of those, probably `<annotation-config>`

Add the following bean declaration in your Config class if not done already

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

In order for `@Value` annotations to work `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` should be registered. It is done automatically when using `<context:property-placeholder>` in XML, but should be registered as a static `@Bean` when using `@Configuration`.

Comment: You're right. We have a generic properties file that loads the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which was not imported yet in this module because that's the first time we use properties in this module. Thanks!