# @Value Property inside @Service Class is Null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Have couple of fields annotated with @Value within the @Service Class.  These fields are not getting populated properly and are null.  Perhaps I overlooked something, I have pasted the relevant blocks of code below.  Tried the alternative option env.getProperty() with same result.

The value of following properties in output are null.

```
package com.project.service.impl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

@Service("aService")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:app.properties")
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
    private Environment environment;
    @Value("${list.size}") 
    private Integer list1;

    @Value("${list2.size}") 
    private Integer list2Size;

    @Autowired 
    public ServiceImpl(StringRedisTemplate stringTemplate){
        this.stringTemplate = stringTemplate;
        logger.info("TESTING 123: "+list1);
    }
    // ...
}

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages =  {"com.project.service","..."})
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();        
        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("app.properties")
        };
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for the class where you're using that service object.

Comment: Also include your imports... you could have the wrong @Value imported.

Comment: @JamieWhite Set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to `false` so you can see if other properties are not found. where in your projectstucture is `app.properties`. Have you tried `new ClassPathResource("/app.properties")
`

Comment: @Jens tried what you suggested but property is still 'null'.

Comment: @JamieWhite Can you please describe you project structure and post the app.propperties file?

Comment: @JamieWhite I am not sure but can it be that you use the wrong syntax?  Can you try @Value("#{list.size}")?

Comment: @JamieWhite does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993766/value-is-not-injected/24993987#24993987) helps you. I have answered there.

Comment: [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Field Injection takes place after construction hence the NullPointer Exception.  Solution is to annotate the constructor params with @Value e.g.

```
public ServiceImpl(StringRedisTemplate stringTemplate, @Value("${list.size}" Integer list1, ..){}
```