# java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null [Multi modules App]

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, mybatis, oauth-2.0

I want to access to my web app by using an oauth2 server.

The authentification pass well and I am redirected to my web app.

But the problem is that when I try to load datas from my data base, I get this

exception :

```
    janv. 31, 2017 1:16:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection connectUsingDriver
    AVERTISSEMENT: Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
    janv. 31, 2017 1:16:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
    GRAVE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
```

Can someone help me please.

**EDIT:**

I have a separate config module where I setup my DB connection. And I add this module like a dependency in my web app.

My application.properties file

```
# DataSource configuration
datasource.host=localhost
datasource.name=my-db
datasource.port=5432

datasource.username=my-user
datasource.password=my-password

datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${datasource.host}:${datasource.port}/${datasource.name}
datasource.driver.class.name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My config class (I am using myBatis like ORM)

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.package.mapper"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.repository"})
public class MyBatisConfig {

  @Value("${datasource.driver.class.name}")
  private String dbDriverClassName;

  @Value("${datasource.url}")
  private String dbUrl;

  @Value("${datasource.username}")
  private String dbUsername;

  @Value("${datasource.password}")
  private String dbPassword;

  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .url(dbUrl)
        .driverClassName(dbDriverClassName)
        .username(dbUsername)
        .password(dbPassword)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("META-INF/spring/mybatis-config.xml"));
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource());
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the configuration of your connections pool (including the connection URL string)  ?

Comment: Could you please post the java code where you are initializing data source/connection?

Comment: @JayaramPradhan yes I edit my post

Comment: @TheGuide: If you will debug, what value you see for `dbUrl` and etc. possibly @Value annotation has not injected the values from properties file.

Comment: @JayaramPradhan, you are right, th value of dbUrl is null

Comment: @TheGuide: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993766/value-is-not-injected

Comment: @JayaramPradhan I try the example in the link but it doesn't work for me. My problem is when I use the annotation EnableOauth2Sso in my class, I cannot inject value in my properties file

Comment: Obviously your `application,properties` file is not being loaded. Investigate; fix.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have to setup DB connection in your configuration files.
Because, from the exception you post i can see that you don't load a Driver for JDBC DriverManager and an URL to access your database.

```
"driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
"url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
"username" value="user"
"password" value="password"
```

this is a simple example of what i'm saying. If i'm wrong please edit your post with your configuration for DB Connection.